# If I have a text(display:none) and a button ,on two different html pages , how can i make the text become visible when i click on the button?

Tags: function, dynamic, onclick

If I have an html page A that contains a text (displayed none) and another page B that contains a button, how can I make the text appear on page A by a click on page B's button?

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you have some sort of server to transmit this updated state to the other page.

Comment: Are you attempting to communicate between two pages that are open at the same time or when navigating from one page to the next? Please revise your question with more details including what you've already tried so that we can better understand your problem.

Comment: @lnogueir There are plenty of ways to facilitate inter-`window` communication including [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) or adding a [`storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) event listener, but the exact implementation depends on more information than the question currently provides.

Comment: @DM Oh good to know! I was not aware of that.

Comment: also useful is the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) in case you don't control opening the pages from your JS code